# How to fix two API requests with flow coroutines

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I have problems to execute two flows with efficient way.
Sometimes I have to trigger this method(click on button) twice to have different result it seems that sometimes flow is not triggered well.
What could be problem here?
My result I would like to achieve.
CLick on button -> 1 flow triggered with success result -> (get data from 1 flow) to trigger 2 flow with new data and with success -> update UI

usecases

```
class GetImageQuotePictureItemUseCase @Inject constructor(private val api: InspirationQuotesApi): BaseFlowOneParameterUseCase<String, Unit, WikipediaPageDetailsResponse>() {
    override fun create(name: String, params: Unit): Flow<WikipediaPageDetailsResponse> {
        return flow{
            emit(api.getImage(name))
        }
    }
}
```

```
class PostInspirationQuote @Inject constructor(private val api: InspirationQuotesApi) :
    BaseApiRequestUseCase<Unit, InspirationQuotesDetailsResponse>() {

    override fun create(params: Unit) = flowSingle {
        api.postQuote()
    }
}
```

viewmodel

```
@HiltViewModel
class InspirationQuotesViewModel @Inject constructor(
    application: Application,
    private val postInspirationQuote: PostInspirationQuote,
    private val getImageQuotePictureItemUseCase: GetImageQuotePictureItemUseCase
) : BaseViewModel() {
    var authorAndQuote: Flow<InspirationQuotesDetailsResponse> = postInspirationQuote.build(Unit)
    fun getImageAuthorFromWikipedia(name: String): Flow<WikipediaPageDetailsResponse> {
        return getImageQuotePictureItemUseCase.build(name, Unit)
    }
}
```

fragment

```
private fun makeApiRequest() {
        var authorName = ""
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            vm.authorAndQuote
                .flowWithLifecycle(lifecycle, Lifecycle.State.RESUMED)
                .collect { response ->
                    authorName = response.quoteAuthor
                    layout.tvAuthor.text = response.quoteAuthor
                    layout.tvQuote.text = response.quoteText
                    if (authorName != "") {
                        vm.getImageAuthorFromWikipedia(authorName)
                            .flowWithLifecycle(lifecycle, Lifecycle.State.STARTED)
                            .collect { response2 ->
                                if (response2 != null && response2.query != null && response2.query.pages != null && response2.query.pages.entries.first() != null && response2.query.pages.entries.first().value.thumbnail != null) {
                                    Glide.with(requireContext())
                                        .load(response2.query.pages.entries.first().value.thumbnail!!.source)
                                        .into(layout.ivImageQuotes)
                                    layout.ivImageQuotes.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                                } else {
                                    Glide.with(requireContext()).load(
                                        ContextCompat.getDrawable(
                                            requireContext(),
                                            R.drawable.offline
                                        )
                                    )
                                        .into(layout.ivImageQuotes)
                                    layout.ivImageQuotes.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                                }
                            }
                    }
                }

        }
    }
```

Comment: See if `flatMapLatest()` or `flatMapConcat()` suits your needs.

Comment: I will check it, but it needs to return Flow value at the end, which I do not do here I only collect and use it,but I will try to manage.

Comment: Maybe I could use something like combine flows?
 https://betterprogramming.pub/learn-how-to-combine-kotlin-flows-317849a71d3e

Comment: I think you can't, because the second request `vm.getImageAuthorFromWikipedia(authorName)` depends on the data (`authorName`) from the first one. `Combine` is used when you have independent `Flow`s.